# Should I add mid-tier (like Java or Node) when working with iOS and Parse (or any other cloud based SDK)?

Tags: ios, security, parse-platform

I am pretty new to iOS and I am planning to start one iOS native application with Parse/AWS or any other cloud based DB handling. Is this a good practice or I should include mid-tier like Java and let my app talking to it instead of directly dealing with Cloud? My question is around security and scalability of my application. If I include a mid-tier then I think I can use that as an API with in Android version of my same app as well and which will make things easier for me to handle.Share your thoughts please.

Answer (score 1):

First, great question. I am a long-time user of Amazon web services, where I call for the database without a middle tier. I find that the cloud balances the load well, spins up new resources well, and generally responds well.

As for the security element, you are really sending authenticated requests directly into the cloud, not to a given server. Hence, making a round trip to a specific server (linux + java) is no longer necessary. The cloud can accept datagrams with authentication information loaded.

I am not a parse person, so I may not get this answer voted, but AWS uses a security service called IAM (Identity and Access Management) which forces you to define a pool of permitted resources in your cloud. I imagine that Parse provides comparable services (if not, perhaps consider the AWS cloud), since this is how you are able to call for the database without a middle server tier.

Comment: Thanks. Its not like I have to use Parse only, I can look at AWS as well.